# Database schema for task management

Tags: mysql

I have to manage a to do list and I'm searching for the best way to implement it in my MySQL database.

My to do list is like the following

- Pre-op

  - Task1
  - Task2
  - Task3
  - Task4
- Receipt images and data

  - Task1
  - Task2
- ...
- ...
- Post-op

  - Task1
  - Task 2

I was thinking to build my schema like this :

```
*************
*** steps ***
*************
id_step 
name_step 

1|Pre-op
2|Receipt images and data
3|...
8|Post-op
```

---

```
*************
*** tasks ***
*************
id_task 
name_task 

1|Task1
2|Task2
3|...
8|Task56
```

---

```
****************
*** todolist ***
****************
id_todolist 
step_id 
task_id
state 

1|1|1|archived
2|1|2|current
3|...
x|8|56|current
```

Am I doing it right ? Or is there a better Way to proceed ?

The differents tasks are unique. And finally I'll have at least two lists like that.

I manage surgical procedures. Currently two patents were filed. So two different ways of managing an operation. In the future, we can imagine that other patents will be filed.

Comment: You want to have a list of steps and each step consists of tasks, which can be completed or not, right? 
Can each task only belong to a single step or can it belong to multiple steps? Will there be more than one list with different levels of completion?

Comment: Yes I want a list of steps subdivised by multiple tasks. The differents tasks are unique. And finally yes I'll have at least two lists like that. Do I have to proceed to change something ?

Comment: 'at least' is the vital phrase here. Why will you have more than one 'list'?

Comment: What is the trick to use if I have several lists?
Do I need to handle this in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is bit late :D but..

I assume you want something like this:
[image: Todolist er diagram]

Here is how you create this setup with some demodata to empty database:

```
CREATE TABLE `todolists` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `order` (`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `todolists` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `order`) VALUES
    (1, 'todolist1name', NULL, 1),
    (2, 'todolist2name', NULL, 2);

CREATE TABLE `steps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `todolist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_in_todolist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `step_order_in_todolist` (`todolist_id`,`order_in_todolist`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1: belong to todolist` FOREIGN KEY (`todolist_id`) REFERENCES `todolists` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `steps` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `todolist_id`, `order_in_todolist`) VALUES
    (1, 'step11name', NULL, 1, 1),
    (2, 'step12name', NULL, 1, 2),
    (3, 'step13name', NULL, 1, 3),
    (6, 'step14name', NULL, 1, 4),
    (7, 'step21name', NULL, 2, 1),
    (8, 'step22name', NULL, 2, 2),
    (9, 'step23name', NULL, 2, 3);

CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `name` char(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `states` (`name`) VALUES
    ('Archived'),
    ('Current');

CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `state` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `step_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_in_steplist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique order in steplist` (`step_id`,`order_in_steplist`),
  KEY `FK1: reference states` (`state`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1: reference states` FOREIGN KEY (`state`) REFERENCES `states` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK2: belongs to step` FOREIGN KEY (`step_id`) REFERENCES `steps` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `state`, `step_id`, `order_in_steplist`) VALUES
    (1, 'Task111name', NULL, 'Archived', 1, 1),
    (2, 'Task112name', NULL, 'Current', 1, 2),
    (3, 'Task113name', NULL, 'Current', 1, 3),
    (4, 'Task114name', NULL, 'Current', 1, 4),
    (5, 'Task121name', NULL, 'Current', 2, 1),
    (6, 'Task122name', NULL, 'Current', 2, 2),
    (7, 'Task123name', NULL, 'Current', 2, 3),
    (8, 'Task131name', NULL, 'Current', 3, 1),
    (9, 'Task132name', NULL, 'Current', 3, 2),
    (10, 'Task133name', NULL, 'Current', 3, 3),
    (12, 'Task141name', NULL, 'Current', 6, 1),
    (13, 'Task142name', NULL, 'Current', 6, 2),
    (14, 'Task143name', NULL, 'Current', 6, 3),
    (15, 'Task211name', NULL, 'Archived', 7, 1),
    (16, 'Task212name', NULL, 'Archived', 7, 2),
    (17, 'Task213name', NULL, 'Archived', 7, 3),
    (18, 'Task221name', NULL, 'Archived', 8, 1),
    (19, 'Task222name', NULL, 'Archived', 8, 2),
    (20, 'Task223name', NULL, 'Current', 8, 3),
    (21, 'Task231name', NULL, 'Current', 9, 1),
    (22, 'Task232name', NULL, 'Current', 9, 2),
    (23, 'Task233name', NULL, 'Current', 9, 3);

CREATE VIEW `show_all_list_with_steps_and_tasks` AS SELECT `todolists`.`order` AS `todolist_number`, `todolists`.`name` AS `todolist_name`, `steps`.`order_in_todolist` AS `step_order`, `steps`.`name` AS step_name, `tasks`.`order_in_steplist` AS `task_order`, `tasks`.`name` AS `task_name`, `tasks`.`state`
FROM `todolists` JOIN `steps` ON `todolists`.`id` = `steps`.`todolist_id` JOIN `tasks` ON `steps`.`id` = `tasks`.`step_id` 
ORDER BY `todolist_number`, `step_order`, `task_order` ;
```

Comment: Done since a long time but this can still help ! I finaly have done something like that ;)

Comment: Yeap, thats what i thought. Just randomly run in to this question and felt need to answer to it as sake of practise :)

Comment: Hi! Why we need order references in all related tables?

Comment: If you mean order, order_in_todolist, order_in_steplist fields they are not references, just int columns to indicate the order of the data row in the list. The reason to have them in all tables is that we want to be able to individually order todo items and steps of the todo item and the tasks of the step.